# Parsing variable byte length message

Tags: parsing, variables, arrays

I'd like to parse a proprietary message with the following format.  The messages are of variable length from 8bytes to 16 bytes.  If the message is more than 8 bytes, it is put into multi packet message.

```
Byte0  Byte1  Byte2 Byte3   Byte4    Byte5   Byte6   Byte7-14 Byte15
Header Header Flags SlaveID Sequence Command Command  Data    Chksum
```

I send these messages to a device and expect a response from said device with similar format.  I know what the messages are supposed to say, but I'm really struggling to find a away to parse the data in real time and display the information in somesort of GUI framework. Currently, I'm planning on dumping the data into a .txt/.csv file and post-processing with matlab.

I'm a hardware guy.  This is not my strong suit.

Example:

Command, Reponse

```
0xAC 04 01 01 00 8C 01 01 chksum
0x04 AC 83 01 00 8C 01 01 0B D9 chksum
```

0x8c01 command to test power supply 0x01
Device echos the command and power supply it was checking and also returns the bit-shifted value of the power supply voltage 0x0BD9

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, what is your question exactly? How are you sending messages to the device, what software or programming language are you using?

Comment: CAN?? CAN can't send message with more than 8 bytes!

Comment: Its not CAN.  Assume its something similar to SAE j1708.  Sending messages with proprietary software.  Pretty sure it utilizes RP1210.

Comment: @user3681498 So What are you expecting? our question is very unclear! And using RP1210 makes it easy to use higher layer protocol! :-)